# Jenkins SonarQube plugin Multi Module Code Coverage Not Displaying

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

so we have a Spring Boot maven based project, which we split into multi modules which all works perfectly fine in unit tests and Jenkins, but coverage is not showing up in Sonar at all.

This is the structure of our application:

```
ApplicationRoot
-SharedCommonModule
--main
---java
-----com...(SomeModule.java)
--test
----com....(SomeModuleTest.java)
-ApplicationModule
--main
---java
-----com...(Application.java)
--test
----com....(ApplicationTest.java)
```

Parent pom file config:

```
<properties>
    <!-- Sonar -->
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <jacoco.destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</jacoco.destFile>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

SharedCommonModule pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main ApplicationModule pom file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.org.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Jenkins SonarQube plugin configuration:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.Application
sonar.projectName=ApplicationModule
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}

sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec

sonar.modules=ApplicationModule,SharedCommonModule

ApplicationModule.sonar.projectName=ApplicationModule
SharedCommonModule.sonar.projectName=SharedCommonModule
```

We have researched and tried to hack it together from multiple examples, but nothing seems to work - closest we've got, is for Sonar to show some coverage, while some classes would show 0% coverage even though we know for sure we have UTs that used those classes (tested via IntelliJ).
So, without without the added `properties` and `build` xml sections above, we get partial coverage, only for ApplicaitonModule, I think all reported uncovered classes, belong to `SharedCommonModule`

EDIT: I want to clarify, the combined jacoco.exec file  does show coverage for classes when loaded in IntelliJ Coverage tool, but Sonar does not show coverage for the very same classes in its report (which is generated only when I remove the `build` and `properties` xml elements in the parent pom).

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have Maven projects, so you should start using [Sonar Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).
It is smart enough to generate all parameters for you.

If you remove:

- `<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>`
- `<jacoco.destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</jacoco.destFile>`
- `<destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>`
- Jenkins SonarQube plugin configuration

add to parent pom file:

```
<name>ApplicationModule</name>
<properties>
    <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    <sonar.projectKey>com.Application</sonar.projectKey>
</properties>
```

add to SharedCommonModule pom file:

```
<name>SharedCommonModule</name>
```

add to ApplicationModule.pom file:

```
<name>ApplicationModule</name>
```

and finally execute:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectVersion="1.0.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

After that you should see missing coverage data.

---

Btw. it is not recomended to set `sonar.projectKey` for Maven projects. I set it to the same value, so your project will be accessible under the same link.